# How to fix "multiple if statements in form validations"

Tags: javascript, validation

I am working on an assignment for university. I need to make a simple form validation system with javascript. The problem is I can't get it right. The first if else statement works perfectly fine, however the second if statement does not work. However, if I copy and paste the second if statement in the console in the browser, it does work. If I try to copy and paste the whole if-else statements it once again does not work.

I have already tried looking at code in other examples but I can't seem to find the solution.

```
let nameForm = $('#name').val();
let age = $("#age").val();
let email = $('#email').val();
let city = $('#city').val();

if(nameForm != ""){
    $("#name").attr("class", function(i, origValue){
        return origValue + " is-valid";
    });
}
else{

    $("#name").attr("class", function(i, origValue){
        return origValue + " is-invalid";
});
}
if(isNaN(age)) {
    $("#age").attr("class", function (i, origValue) {
        return origValue + " is-valid";
    });
}
```

I have tried to remove all attr() and replace it with addClass(). This is the code I have now but still the class is-valid is not added with input age.

```
if(nameForm != ""){
    $("#name").removeClass("is-invalid");
    $("#name").addClass("is-valid");
}
else if(nameForm === "") {
    $("#name").removeClass("is-valid");
    $("#name").addClass("is-invalid");
}
if(isNaN(age)){
    alert('test2');
    $("#age").removeClass("is-invalid");
    $("#age").addClass("is-valid");
}
```

The only error I got is this:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) But this is for the styles.css file and that file is empty.

Comment: the problem in your code is that after the first if - else statement you ALWAYS return something. So the next if statement is never checked.
If you need more hints I will explain further...

Comment: Use the `.addClass()` function

Comment: The `returns` are fine -- they happen within jquery's `attr` method.

Comment: "It does not work" doesn't describe what you're expecting or what actually happens.

Comment: Tom is of course correct. Don't mind my first comment

Comment: @FrisoStolk, you should answer your own question below so others can see what your mistake was and how to fix it.

Comment: @FrisoStolk Do not add statements like "answered" in the title. That is what we have _answer_ for.

Comment: You know what? Every time you use `$("#name")` it is like flying to the moon to take a picture of a rock, and then return to earth, only to look a the picture one time before trowing it away, and then send another crew to the moon to take an exact same picture of the exact same rock...  Don't do unnecessary trips to the moon! Save the value in a variable an reuse it!!!!